# Toggle an inline application to full screen?

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way to toggle an inline application to full screen? I would like to use a standalone application, but to meet an agency requirement I need to initially start it in a container within the existing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to stretch the isle your inline app in running in to full browser size via HTML / CSS. That should do the job, but you will still stick to the inline app approach which should not harm in any way.